# exec() command not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, python, wordpress

Does anyone know of this issue? I am using `exec()` command to execute my python script from wordpress(WordPress 4.4.2 i),But Its not returning anything,I am using windows 7 /wamp. when I tried to run the same script from `/wamp/www` its working fine.
here is my php script:

```
exec("C:\Python27\python.exe D:\wamp\www\python_script.py ",$out);
echo '<pre>';print_r($out);
```

In python I am just trying to `print 'Hello World';`

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

You're using `"`-quoted strings, so `C:\Python27\python.exe D:\wamp\www\python_script.py` is actually parsed as `C:Python27python.exe D:wampwwwptyhon_script.py` - the `\P`, `\p`, `\w` etc are NOT string metacharacters, so the escape is simply lost in PHP, and never reaches the shell you're executing.

You need

```
exec("C:\\Python27\\python.exe D:\\wamp\\www\\python_script.py ",$out);
```

instead. Note the doubled `\\`.

And note that this has nothing to do with Wordpress. This is a PHP "problem".

Comment: Yes,I can Understand. But the problem is with wordpress.